# How to repent for breaking relationship?

Tags: relationships

I used to like a guy a few years a back. I was 19 back then. I was obsessed with him. I used to make dua to get him as my husband. But i didn’t know if he had any girlfriend or not. But i asked for his break up if he had any girlfriend. But now i don’t have such feelings for him. I didn’t know about his girlfriend. Will Allah forgive me during this month of Ramadan for asking for someone's break up?

Comment: What you've done is not sinful in fact keeping that relationship would be. Breaking it up is a major step for repentance in that case.

Answer (score 0):

No matter how grave your sin is, the forgiveness of Allah, The Almighty, is greater. So, you should not despair of His Mercy, nor should you lose faith in the vastness of His Forgiveness.
The Prophet (saws) says:

> “By the One in Whose hand is my soul, if you did not commit sin Allah would do away with > you and bring people who would commit sin then pray for forgiveness.”
>
>  **-Narrated by Muslim, 2749**

Allah Says in the Quran:

> “And who despairs of the mercy of his Lord except for those astray?”
>
>  **-Quran 15:56**

> "Indeed, no one despairs of relief from Allah except the disbelieving
> people." 
>  **-Quran 12:87**

> "Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by
> sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah. Indeed, Allah forgives
> all sins. Indeed, it is He Who is the Forgiving, the Merciful."
>
>  **-Quran 39:53**

The Prophet (saws) said:

> “Verily, Allah stretches out His Hand during the night so that the one
> who committed sins during the daytime would repent, and He stretches
> out His Hand during the day so that the one who committed sins at
> night would repent (and He will continue to do so) until the sun rises
> from the West.”
>
>  **-Muslim**

He (saws) also said:

> “The one who repents of sin is like one who has not sinned.”  
> **-Ibn Maajah**

Therefore, you should expect the best from Allah, The Exalted, sincerely and honestly repent to Him and regret your sins. Such remorse is an essential consequence of realizing the heinousness and gravity of the sin. When one realizes the gravity and evil consequences of committing a sin, he inevitably feels remorseful about it. So quit your sins immediately, resolve to never commit them again, and regret having done so. Beware of the severe punishment and vengeance of Allah, The Almighty. Just as He is All-Forgiving and Merciful to those who repent, He is also capable of retribution against those who persistently and stubbornly commit sin. Allah Says:

> "[O Muhammad] inform My servants that it is I who am the Forgiving,
> the Merciful. And that it is My punishment which is the painful
> punishment." 
>  **-Quran 15:49-50**

> "Indeed, your Lord is swift in penalty; but indeed, He is Forgiving
> and Merciful."
>
>  **-Quran 7:167**